# Why Babel copies my JS-files without conversion from JS6 to JS5?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have a problem with [Babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/). It copies my JS-files without conversion from JS6 to JS5. [Here](https://github.com/Andrey-Bushman/babel-sandbox) is my small "Hello World" project code sources for demonstrate of this problem.

In the `scripts` section of the `project.json` file I added the row:

```
"babel": "babel src/js -d test/lib"
```

I launch it by the command:

```
npm run babel
```

Why does it happen?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't tell it do any conversion

Comment: @Quentin I do it according the official example: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: There are **lots** of examples on that page, and your code doesn't match any of them. (It doesn't even come *close* to matching any of the examples which modify the code).

Comment: @Quentin look first example this section: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/#babel-compile-directories

Comment: It uses `--out-dir`, you use `-d`, so it doesn't match … and that example doesn't transform the code in any way. It is just showing you how to specify what directories to work on.

Comment: (I'm assuming you haven't bothered creating a `.bablerc` since you didn't mention on in the question).

Comment: @Quentin that section writes that `-d` is short variant of  `--out-dir`.

Comment: Not the main point of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer myself. I publish it here so that newcomers such as myself do not stumble on the same rake.

It is necessary to install [babel-preset-es2015](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/#install) and add the [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/#usage-via-babelrc-recommended-) file. Now it works.